# Simpleform fields_for and nested_routes not working on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to get this `fields_for` on `simple_form` working with Rails 4:

Below is my form:

```
= simple_form_for(hall_webcasts_path(@hall), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, :wrapper => "horizontal", defaults: { :input_html => { class: "form-control"}, label_html: { class: "col-lg-4" } } ) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.simple_fields_for @webcast do |b|
    .form-inputs
      = b.input :name
      = b.association :hall, prompt: "Choose a hall", :input_html => { class: "chosen" }
      = b.input :webcast_type
      = b.input :media_type
      = b.association :user, prompt: "Choose a user", :input_html => { class: "chosen" } if current_user.has_role? :admin
      = b.input :user, as: :hidden, :value => current_user.id if !current_user.has_role? :admin
      = b.input :details
      = b.association :template, :input_html => { class: "chosen" }
      = b.input :background_colour, :input_html => { "colourpicker" => "true" }
      = b.input :start, as: :string, :input_html => { class: "datetimepicker form-control" }
      = b.input :finish, as: :string, :input_html => { class: "datetimepicker form-control" }

    .form-actions
      = b.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Below is my routes:

```
    resources :venues, shallow: true do
        #Halls
        get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
        get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
        get "structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
        resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
        resources :halls do
            resources :webcasts
            resources :booths do
                resources :chats
            end
        end
    end
```

This however always create:

```
/halls/1/webcasts/new
```

In my form action and something like below:

```
/halls/1/webcasts[webcast][name]
```

in my input fields `name` attributes.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
class Webcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hall
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :template

  validates :name, :hall, :user, :template, presence: :true

end
```

I also added `webcast` model for reference

Comment: `Is there a way to fix this issue?` what issue? what do you expect?

Comment: @emaillenin it's going to the wrong url `/halls/1/webcasts/new` which doesn't support post route to invoke `webcasts#create` action

Comment: whats the correct url that you expect here?